# How to have my program stops if its memory consumption exceeds a limit ?

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management

I develop a C++ framework that is used to run user code in a well defined environment (Linux boxes under our supervision).

I would like to prevent badly written modules to start eating up all memory of a machine. As I develop the framework could I simply force the program to stop itself if its memory consumption is too high ? What api or tool should I use for this ?

Comment: The OS will stop the program if it eats to much memory, but besides from that the only thing I can think of is writing your own memory management module which will stop the program when it has used a predefined amount of memory.

Comment: This morning the OS happily killed a system process instead of the rogue process. This is why we would like something more preventive.

Comment: That would be a problem of course :)

Comment: @Barth How about running a monitoring process which will periodically call ps aux command?

Comment: You might look at `man bash` and look under `ulimit` that restricts a given shell.

Comment: @MNS We have zabbix running. Would you advise about having such a tool kill the process ?

Comment: @Barth I haven't used Zabix. But whatever mechanism you use to monitor memory usage of a process, it should NOT kill a process rather it should be a graceful exit. Since you are developing a framework, firstly, you can have a container executable. Secondly, let the the modules be developed as libraries (*.so) and the container can load and execute library modules. Thirdly, let there be a monitoring process. When the monitoring process identifies that a process has exceeded the limit, let him send a notification to the container executable so that it can gracefully exit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple mechanism for controlling a process's resource limits is provided by [`setrlimit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html). But that doesn't isolate the process (as you should for untrusted third-party code), it only puts some restrictions on it. To properly isolate a process from the rest of the system, you should either use a VM, or make use of cgroups and kernel namespaces — preferrably not by hand, but via some existing library or framework (such as Docker).

Comment: We consider Docker for the coming rewrite of this program but for now it is a legacy code that we have to support. I will therefore go for strlimit I presume.

Answer (score 2):

> How to have my program stops if its memory consumption exceeds a limit ?

When you define the interface between the application and it's modules, ensure that one of the first steps (probably the first) will be to pass an allocator-like class instance, from the application to the modules.

This instance should be used in the module to allocate and deallocate all necessary memory.

This will allow implementations of this allocator instance, to report memory allocations to the main application, which should be able to triggering an exception, if a limit (per module or per application) is reached.

Comment: There's no need to pass such an allocator, we already pass `operator new` implicitly. It may not be a class, but it does generate an exception (std::bad_alloc). The benefit of stciking with the standard is that a lot of code already follows this convention.

Comment: I realize the module code will have access to operator new, but the OP asked for the possibility to set a custom / arbitrary limit. This would require a custom operator new with lots of hidden state, or a custom memory manager/tracker/allocator.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly provide your own `operator new`. However, that won't protect you from calls to `malloc`, or direct OS calls. This would require patching or wrapping glibc (since you're on Linux). Doable but not nice.

What's your desired security level? Are you protecting against Murphy or Machiavelli ? Might a plugin use a third-party library which allocates memory on bahalf of the plugin? Do you need to keep track of the plugin that allocated the memory?

Comment: Some people might use malloc. They are not evil, just ... uninformed. And some seem to still live in the C not++ world. Each process loads a single plugin, therefore we implicitely know which plugin has allocated memory when we see the corresponding process's memory growing.